# Add text / html in a empty node like text node

Tags: javascript, html

I have this function I am calling from rich text editor to add the content in the selection.

The problem is, it is not working properly, if I pass with html tags like `<center>some</center>`

Instead of making the content center, it outputs the HTML also text

```
function addTextAtCursorPostion(text) {
var sel, range, html;
if (window.getSelection) {
    sel = window.getSelection();
    if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
        range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
        range.deleteContents();
        range.insertNode(document.createTextNode(text));
    }
}
```

This `document.createTextNode` takes only text. Is there a way i can process text and html?

or ***do we have any dummy/empty node that can place html inside?***

Sample Content of my Rich Text Editor innerHTML taken using Firebug

```
<div contenteditable="true" id="editor">
      <font face="Comic Sans MS">Go ahead</font>…
       <a href="www.stackoverflow.com"><b><i>Welcome User</i>
  **ADD HTML FORMATTED STRING HERE OR POSITION AT CURSOR**
 </b></a><br>
</div>
```

If i wrap my htmlText with `span/div/p` i may get UI alignment issue

Comment: Why not create a `center` node instead of a text node?

Comment: What is `range`? If it's an element, you can use `range.innerHTML = text`.

Comment: @Todd, Range don't have innerHTML. [Read this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/range)

Comment: @Billa, thanks for the link. I wasn't familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can render HTML using a text node. You'll need to create an element and use `innerHTML` to insert the code.

```
var el = document.createElement('span');
el.innerHTML = text;
```

Comment: This `<div>` tag will cause aligment issue. Is there any other element which wont do any alignment issue?

Comment: You can use a `span` element. Any alignment issues can be ironed out with a bit of CSS.

Comment: See the updated question. The Rich text editor may contain any HTML inside. How do you adjust the CSS with out knowing the HTML output?

Comment: Only adjusting the CSS of the containing element - in this case that would be an inline `span` element.

Comment: What css you would adjust, when the previous element is in any of absolute/relative/static or float left/right and top,left values assigned?

Comment: If you're able to reproduce the scenario in a jsfiddle I'd be happy to help - but I'm having a bit of an issue figuring out what you're trying to accomplish in concerns to layout.

Comment: I got the list of layouts defined in HTML standard format and stored in the database. Now i want to add it in middle of editor content or i may load that into editor and update it.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but I'm thinking you could insert the HTML string into a custom HTML Element (which bring no inherited styles, other than those added globally) and then insert that into the range.

```
function addTextAtCursorPostion(text) {
 var sel, range, html;
 if (window.getSelection) {
   sel = window.getSelection();
   if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
      range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
      range.deleteContents();
      range.insertNode(document.createElement("range").innerHTML=text);
  }
```

}

Comment: The problem is UI alignment may come. Please see the sample content of my editor above

Comment: There, use a custom HTML element. It's just a wrapper, there will be no inherited styles (other than those applied to *)